# How can we add serial number (S.No.) in Jtable which gets updated each time we delete the data of a table?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How can we add row that contain serial number (S.No.) in Jtable which gets updated each time we delete the data of a table?
e.g.:
i have a jtable which contain data from database

```
Name Age Class
ram  14  9
hari 15  9
rama 15  10
```

i want it to be like this:

```
S.No. Name Age Class
1     Ram  14   9
2     hari 15   9
3     rama 15   10
```

And if i delete data of hari this table should look like this:

```
S.No. Name Age Class
1     Ram  14   9
2     rama 15   10
```

Comment: what should be updated? the rows? just the `S.No.`?

Comment: the S.No. should be updated

Comment: in that case you will have to give examples. give 5 example rows and remove 1

Comment: can I assume that you maintain a list of all the object within your class?

Answer (score 1):

This code assumes, that you maintain a list of all students and have everywhere in the class access to the table as well as the model.

```
public void stuff() {
    deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            list.remove(table.getSelectedRow());
            removeRowsFromTable();
        }
    });

}

void removeRowsFromTable() throws Exception {
    for (int i = table.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        model.removeRow(i);
    }
    fillTable();
}

void fillTable() {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Student s = list.get(i);
        Object[] newRow = new Object[] {i, s.getName(),s.getAge(), s.getClass()};
        model.addRow(newRow);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using 
ResultSet rs=DB.searchQuery("SELECT * FROM student");
jTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

Comment: then you have to map each entry of the resultset to a new student first and create a lsit of students. also you will need to create the tablemodel by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Do following thing:

- Move your code to a method in which you are filling the table
- Add `ActionPerformed` listener to your delete button
- In the implementation of `ActionPerformed` call that method again will refresh the table with new entries.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I have done that but my confuse is about S.No., I am unable to add a row that shows S.No. which updated if we do delete operation

Comment: could you post our code so we can examine that code and give you any possible solution.

Comment: i am using ResultSet rs=DB.searchQuery("SELECT * FROM student"); jTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

Answer (score 0):

```
 jTableModel.removeRow(rowIndex);
 for(int i = rowIndex; i < jTableModel.getRowCount(); i++){
     int val = (int) jTableModel.getValueAt(i, 0);
     jTableModel.setValueAt(--val, i, 0);
 }
```